# Correspondence between ground state and steady state in quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

An open quantum system $S$ is usually studied by considering a system of interest effectively interacting with an environment $E$. The environment is treated effectively because of the difficulty of treating all its degrees of freedom with the quantum theory. If we had a computer able to simulate this large quantum system (i.e. $S+E$), we could compute its ground state.

Is there any relation between this ground state (which is obtained by diagonalising $\hat{H}|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle$) of $S+E$ and the steady-state of the system $S$? Is there any literature on this (a quick google search did not rise any interesting results)?

---

Just to explain my doubt a bit further, I'm thinking that if $|\psi\rangle$ is the ground state of $S+E$, then the time evolution of the system, if prepared in that state, would be $|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-i\omega_0t}|\psi\rangle$, which oscillates. Thus it does not have a fixed-point, as usually happens for the steady-state of an open quantum system with dissipation (because the dynamical map is not unitary). However, there should be some relation between the ground state $|\psi\rangle$ and the steady-state.

Answer (score 6):

The system + environment will *not* go into its ground state if it is isolated.  In fact, it will not even go to an equilibrium state but keep evolving under the unitary dynamics govered by the total Hamiltonian. However, if the environment is much larger than the system, then effectively, the reduced density matrix of the system will be in a steady state (up to small fluctuations in time); this is closely related to the [eigenstate thermalization hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenstate_thermalization_hypothesis). This is not so different from how a classical Gibbs state is described by considering a subsystem of an isolated system (i.e. constructing a canonical ensemble as part of a microcanonical ensemble).